# Get all headers from URL, when working with port connection

Tags: php, linux, url, port, get-request

I'm busy with a tracking script to handle connections and read the information from a tracking unit. But the way the manufacturer explained it to me, is that the unit sends the information like a URL and it connects to a TCP port, for example: 7203.

Now my question is: how do I get the headers with a unit that connects to my server, when working with a port? And I also run the code from a Linux Command line.

Below is the code I use to open a port:

```
#!/usr/bin/php -q
<?php
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);
    set_time_limit(0);
    ob_implicit_flush();
    $ip = 'IP of my server';
    $port = '7203';
    $__server_listening = true;

    declare(ticks = 1);

    become_daemon();

    /* nobody/nogroup, change to your host's uid/gid of the non-priv user 

    ** Comment by Andrew - I could not get this to work, i commented it out
       the code still works fine but mine does not run as a priv user anyway....
       uncommented for completeness
    */
    change_identity(99, 99);

    /* handle signals */
    pcntl_signal(SIGTERM, 'sig_handler');
    pcntl_signal(SIGINT, 'sig_handler');
    pcntl_signal(SIGCHLD, 'sig_handler');

    /* change this to your own host / port */
    server_loop($ip, $port);

    /**
      * Change the identity to a non-priv user
      */
    function change_identity( $uid, $gid )
    {
        if( !posix_setgid( $gid ) )
        {
            print "Unable to setgid to " . $gid . "!\n";
            exit;
        }

        if( !posix_setuid( $uid ) )
        {
            print "Unable to setuid to " . $uid . "!\n";
            exit;
        }
    }

    /**
      * Creates a server socket and listens for incoming client connections
      * @param string $address The address to listen on
      * @param int $port The port to listen on
      */
    function server_loop($address, $port)
    {
        GLOBAL $__server_listening;

        if(($sock = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) < 0)
        {
            echo "failed to create socket: ".socket_strerror($sock)."\n";
            exit();
        }

        if(($ret = socket_bind($sock, $address, $port)) < 0)
        {
            echo "failed to bind socket: ".socket_strerror($ret)."\n";
            exit();
        }

        if( ( $ret = socket_listen( $sock, 0 ) ) < 0 )
        {
            echo "failed to listen to socket: ".socket_strerror($ret)."\n";
            exit();
        }

        socket_set_nonblock($sock);

        echo "waiting for clients to connect on $address:$port\n";

        while ($__server_listening)
        {
            $connection = @socket_accept($sock);
            if ($connection === false)
            {
                usleep(100);
            }
            elseif ($connection > 0)
            {
                handle_client($sock, $connection);
            }
            else
            {
                echo "error: ".socket_strerror($connection);
                die;
            }
        }
    }

    /**
    * Signal handler
    */
    function sig_handler($sig)
    {
        switch($sig)
        {
            case SIGTERM:
            case SIGINT:
                //exit();
            break;

            case SIGCHLD:
                pcntl_waitpid(-1, $status);
            break;
        }
    }

    /**
    * Handle a new client connection
    */
    function handle_client($ssock, $csock)
    {
        GLOBAL $__server_listening;

        $pid = pcntl_fork();

        if ($pid == -1)
        {
            /* fork failed */
            echo "fork failure!\n";
            die;
        }
        elseif ($pid == 0)
        {
            /* child process */
            $__server_listening = false;
            socket_getpeername($csock, $remip, $remport);
            print date("d-m-y H:i:s") . " Connection from $remip:$remport\r\n\r\n";
            socket_close($ssock);
            interact($csock);
            socket_close($csock);
            print date("d-m-y H:i:s") . " Connection to $remip:$remport closed\r\n\r\n";
            print "------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------\r\n\r\n";
        }
        else
        {
            socket_close($csock);
        }
    }

    function interact($socket)
    {
        $gets = $_REQUEST;
        print $gets;
    }

    /**
      * Become a daemon by forking and closing the parent
      */
    function become_daemon()
    {
        $pid = pcntl_fork();

        if ($pid == -1)
        {
            /* fork failed */
            echo "fork failure!\n";
            exit();
        }
        elseif ($pid)
        {
            /* close the parent */
            exit();
        }
        else
        {
            /* child becomes our daemon */
            posix_setsid();
            //chdir('/');
            //umask(0);
            return posix_getpid();

        }
    } 

?>
```

Where the function **interact** is, is where the connection is already made and I should be able to read the headers. But no joy. The error I receive is: **Notice: Array to string conversion in /home/armand/bin/7203/7203.php on line 198**

And the information that the unit sends looks like this:

> 357671030507047#V500#0000#AUTOLOW#1#00ab46cb,0,0,0,2,09,14,$GPRMC,073106.000,A,2647.0278,S,02750.8628,E,0.00,324.27,021213,,,A*7C##`

Comment: Is it HTTP protocol ? then configure your http server to listen on that port. If not you should ask what is the protocol.

Comment: Hi yes sorry I read that its an HTTP protocol. I'm not that much familiar with setting up a HTTP server to listen on a port. Do you maybe have an example code I could work from?

Comment: **on line 198** - The code you posted has less than 198 lines, so I doubt it is the one that produces the error.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [built-in http server in PHP](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php) with this command

> php -S localhost:7203

or if you use an apache http server, in the configuration file use

> Listen *:7203

Comment: I have tried php -S localhost:7203 but receive the following error in Putty: [Wed Dec  4 09:49:39 2013] 41.13.4.237:59024 Invalid request (Malformed HTTP request). What could be the problem?

Comment: An http request call a php script to be executed. You need to give me the http headers to see what the server receive and how to answer it. I think you should consider using Node.js because it seems that it is a special url request.